# Это баг или последствия действий кого-то из участников?

Tags: обсуждение, дефект

Зашёл в раздел репутации и увидел такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне стало интересно что это. Я подумал, что ошибка системы, ведь это все минусы появились в интервале почти меньше секунды..

Но, возможно, это делают нарочно. Если даже так, то как бороться с такими недоброжелателями?

*P.S. Впервые задаю тут вопрос, возможно и без пользы другим, но очень уж интересно выяснить в чём проблема :)*

Comment: Пользователи бывают разные, скорее всего какие-то эмоционально неустойчивые, не удержались. Хотя, какой в этом смысл? Не понятно.

Comment: Мое мнение по поводу минусов такое, они необходимы, если вопрос неадекватен (явно не по теме и т .д.), или же человек задает вопросы, которые явно не принесут пользы сообществу в ближайшей перспективе. Все остальные случаи, это или +, или ничего... Я вам ставлю +1, вопрос хороший, сталкивался, только в меньших масштабах.

Comment: Минусы для того и есть.. а тут их не в том направлении используют..

Comment: It's just a prank.

Comment: @Suvitruf для кого-то да, а для кого-то это не приятно.

Comment: Это всего лишь рейтинг. Ну и в любом случае дождитесь завтрашнего дня, система распознать должна такие вещи.

Comment: Вас тут двое таких, кто получил от некоего пользователя 10 и 20 минусов. Завтра эти минусы должны будут быть автоматически отменены.